# How to program Atmel ATtiny88 (not 45 or 85)?

Tags: programming, atmel, attiny

There are lots of tutorials for programming the ATtiny45 and 85 with a breadboard and Arduino, but how would I program the [ATtiny88](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY88.aspx)? It's an 8 bit AVR microcontroller, but it can not be mounted on a breadboard.

Comment: The ATTiny88-PU is a 28 pin DIP that can be plugged into a breadboard, so should be able to be programmed same as the 45 and 85 (with due regard to pinout).  If you're using a surface-mount version, the PC board should include a programming header.

Comment: Why can't you mount ATtiny88-PU on a breadboard?

Comment: @Chetan I'm going to guess that the ATtiny88 the OP has is a surface mount package, and he or she is erroneously thinking that one difference between the ATtiny45/85 and 88 is the package.

Answer (score 4):

The device comes out in TQFP, VQFN and PDIP packages

[image]

I can only assume that you don't have the PDIP version so what you can do for SMD versions is to use a reusable adapter like

[image]

The alternative are solderable adapters but they may not be convenient if after programming you intend to solder the chip on a board.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### ISP

Like other AVR microcontrollers The ATtiny88 allows for in-system programming (ISP) using it's Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) bus. It can therefore be programmed like any other AVR with that feature.

### avrdude & ArduinoISP

You can use the avrdude program to read a compiled binary file and write it to an AVR chip via an Arduino running the "Arduino as ISP" sketch. You just use the appropriate command-line options `avrdude -c arduino -p t88 ...` and make the relevant connections between SPI interfaces (SCLK, MISO, MOSI) plus Pin10->RESET, VCC and GND.

### Arduino IDE

Many of the online tutorials for the ATtiny85 etc assume you are using the Arduino IDE to write and compile your programs. The Arduino IDE uses add-in "cores" which define the pinouts and capabilities of each AVR chip the IDE can target. To target an ATtiny88 you'd have to find or create a "core" and add it to the appropriate folder/subdirectory in the IDE installation.

### Other IDE/compilers

If you are not using the Arduino IDE you can still use avrdude and an Arduino as programmer to write your compiled binary to the ATtiny88.